# Invariance of Solution of Laplace equation on $\mathcal{B}_{1}(0)$ under funny composition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Suppose $v:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ solves $\Delta v=0$ on $\mathcal{B}_{1}(0)$. Let $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$ and define $M:\mathcal{B}_{1}(0)\rightarrow\mathcal{B}_{1}(0)$ by $M(x,y)=(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,\,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta).$ Define $u:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $u(x,y)=v(M(x,y)).$ Show that $u$ solves $\Delta u=0$ on $\mathcal{B}_{1}(0).$

---

I am sure we have to use the chain rule to show that $\Delta u=0.$ I have that

$$\partial_{x}u=\cos\theta\,\cdot\partial_{x}v+\sin\theta\,\cdot\partial_{y}v,$$

$$\partial^{2}_{x}u=\cos\theta\left[ \cos\theta\,\cdot\partial^{2}_{x}v+\sin\theta\,\cdot\partial^{2}_{xy}v \right]+\sin\theta\left[ \cos\theta\,\cdot\partial^{2}_{xy}v+\sin\theta\,\cdot\partial^2_{y}v \right],$$

$$\partial_{y}u=-\sin\theta\,\cdot\partial_{x}v+\cos\theta\,\cdot\partial_{y}v$$

$$\partial^{2}_{y}u=-\sin\theta\left[ -\sin \theta\,\cdot \partial^{2}_{x}v + \cos \theta\, \cdot \partial^{2}_{xy}v \right] + \cos \theta \left[ -\sin \theta\, \cdot \partial^{2}_{xy}v + \cos \theta\, \cdot \partial^2_{y}v \right].$$

From the above it follows that $\Delta u=0.$

---

Is the above computation correct? Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Your computation is correct. There is nothing weird about $M$. It is  simply rotation by angle $\theta$.